# Polymorphism in C++ with shared inheritance

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm looking at implementing a suite of point types used in GIS, which are either 2D (xy), 3D (xyz or xym) or 4D (xyzm). The M-coordinate is a measure coordinate, and the others should be obvious. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the `PointZM` class share the `x` and `y` members from the `Point` class. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
  public:
    double x, y;
    Point (double xNew, double yNew) : x(xNew), y(yNew) {};
};

class PointZ : public Point {
  public:
    double z;
    PointZ (double xNew, double yNew, double zNew) :
        Point(xNew, yNew), z(zNew) {};
};

class PointM : public Point {
  public:
    double m;
    PointM (double xNew, double yNew, double mNew) :
        Point(xNew, yNew), m(mNew) {};
};

class PointZM : public PointZ, public PointM {
  public:
      PointZM (double xNew, double yNew, double zNew, double mNew) :
          PointZ(xNew, yNew, zNew), PointM(xNew, yNew, mNew) {};
};

int main () {
    Point p (1, 2);
    PointZ pZ (1, 2, 3);
    PointM pM (1, 2, 4);
    PointZM pZM (1, 2, 3, 4);
    std::cout << "Point: " << sizeof(p) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PointZ: " << sizeof(pZ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PointM: " << sizeof(pM) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PointZM: " << sizeof(pZM) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints the size of the four instances of each class:

```
Point: 16
PointZ: 24
PointM: 24
PointZM: 48
```

I was expecting the last `PointZM` to be 32 bytes, as it should have `x`, `y`, `z` and `m` members. How can I get the two inherited classes `PointZ` and `PointM` to share their inherited `Point` members? Is the some way to get the union of two classes? I'm a C++ novice with this topic.

The motivation on why to bother with inheritance is not apparent with simple point geometries. However, when further developing different geometry types, like `LineString` (2D), `LineStringZ` (3D), `LineStringM` (3D) or `LineStringZM` (4D), they would have a `length` method which would be different if there was a Z-dimension. The length method would be calculated differently only if there is a Z-dimension, and I wouldn't want to double the efforts to add this to `LineStringZ` and `LineStringZM` classes.

Comment: `PointZM` has two `Point` instances. Anyway, inheritance doesn't look right here. I wouldn't say a 4D point *is-a* 2D point.

Comment: Check out virtual base classes; but honestly inheritance here is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Would class templates be a better idea here? Again, I'm a novice in this territory.

Comment: What's the problem with just making them four distinct, unrelated, classes?

Comment: Different types, function overloads to operate on different types (in different combinations, where applicable.) Class and function templates might help implementing this (I would do that), but you can also do it without them.

Comment: @juanchopanza This. However isn't 4D point 2D point in 2D projection of the 4D space? [OPINION] But I would also avoid inheritance here and instead I would use POD as these points will be likely used in array which should be castable to double* array. (On the other hand, I would implement operators converting 2D, 3D and 4D points, probably requiring explicit cast in order to avoid typos and random errors.) [/OPINION]

Comment: @Laethnes But which projection? There are many ways to map a 4D space to a 2D one. Inheritance really does not model this well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).  This would make PointZM contain just one Point, rather than two.  You might later decide this isn't worth the complexity, and instead just implement PointZ, PointM, and PointZM separately, but that's up to you.

On my system, virtual inheritance adds 8 bytes to each virtually-derived type, and PointZM stays the same size because the 16 bytes of the extra Point it contained are removed but we now have two extra pointers stored for the virtual base classes.  So then the sizes look like this:

```
Point: 16
PointZ: 32
PointM: 32
PointZM: 48
```

Comment: [OPINION] Even though it is correct, I would avoid virtual inheritance (and virtual anything) in this case. There is probably going to be a big array of these and in that case each byte counts. As I wrote in comments of main question, I would go for separate POD. [/OPINION]

Comment: @Laethnes: I would do the same as you if high performance is desired.

Answer (score 5):

There is 2D geometry, 3D geometry and 4D geometry. 3D geometry is not a refined instance of 2D geometry, it is a totally different beast. Likewise 4D geometry is not a special case of 3D geometry.

Public inheritance is intended to express the *is-a* relationship. There's no such relationship between differently dimensioned geometries.

Non-public inheritance can be used for code sharing, but it is not clear what code can be shared between 2D, 3D and 4D cases.

However, all of those geometries are cases of *generic N-dimensioned geometry*, N being a parameter. It would be natural to model this with a class template.

```
   template <size_t N>
   class Point
   {
      std::array<double, N> coord;
      // ... rest of the code ...
   };
```